# Rails - Change TimeWithZone Timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I've been banging my head against this for a while and I can't seem to understand how rails timezones and `in_time_zone` works.

Here is some `rails c` output that I'd like to understand:

```
[26] VMM(bby - main - dev)> Time.zone.now
=> Wed, 14 Mar 2018 09:13:17 CDT -05:00
[27] VMM(bby - main - dev)> MyModel.first.started_at
=> Fri, 09 Mar 2018 09:17:00 CST -06:00
[28] VMM(bby - main - dev)> MyModel.first.started_at.in_time_zone(Time.zone)
=> Fri, 09 Mar 2018 09:17:00 CST -06:00
```

So:

- From the first line, the Time.zone seems to be `CDT -5`.
- From the second line, the `started_at` attribute seem to be `CST -6`
- On the third line, my intention is to change that atribute to use `CDT -5`, so I'd expect an output of `Fri, 09 Mar 2018 10:17:00 CDT -05:00`

Why does this behave as it does instead of how I expect it to?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your config.time_zone in config/application.rb?

Comment: Central Time (US & Canada)

Comment: I'm guessing this is because DST started on the 11th...

Comment: Yup, it was what triggered this thing, the system was working just fine til this Monday!